# VSCode is giving error "No module named sqlalchemy" despite module being installed in the python enviornment

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a basic sqlAlchemy program and trying to import the module as shown in ***block 1*** of the picture.
[image]

***Block 2*** shows that the code gives me the error that the module is missing.
However if you see ***block 4*** ( the second part of split-ted console), you would see that the sqlAlchemy module is very much installed in the environment.

Also note from ***block 3*** that I am using a virtual environment which is active as the console suggests.

Any help in explaining the reason why this is happening would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `from sqlalchemy import create_engine` as `import`

Comment: @ilja , thanks for your reply but its not working that way either.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your block 4 you will notice you are using an Anaconda install for that import while block 3 shows you're using a virtual environment when trying to execute the code. I suspect that if you open the Python interpreter as specified when executing your script (`/Users/.../Desktop/PyProject/venv/Scripts/python.exe`) and then try `import sqlalchemy` at the REPL then the import won't work. Or put another way, the `python` you manually launched may not be pointing to the one set as the interpreter in VS Code.